# What does this C language statement mean?

Tags: c, function, types, syntax, function-pointers

```
int (*EVP_MD_meth_get_cleanup(const EVP_MD *md))(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx)
```

I find this code piece, not sure how to understand it. I think *EVP_MD_meth_get_cleanup* is the name of the function pointer type, return *int*, but not understand the argument part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EVP_MD_meth_get_cleanup`  is a function, that takes `const EVP_MD *md` as an argument, and *returns a function pointer*. That function pointer takes `EVP_MD_CTX *ctx` and returns an `int`.

Nothing better than an example:

```
int somefunction(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx) {
    stuff();
}

int (*EVP_MD_meth_get_cleanup(const EVP_MD *md))(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx) {
   return somefunction;
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine https://godbolt.org/z/a1ajdK5b9